# Angular dynamic controller / templateUrl

Tags: javascript, angularjs, route-provider, ngroute

I am trying to build my first angular app and looking to setup dynamic routing so that I can build out the app without having to continuously add to the `$routeProvider` config. I haven't quite found the simplest / cleanest approach yet, any guidance is much appreciated. Below was my first approach.

```
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']).config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider', function($locationProvider, $routeProvider){
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        redirectTo: '/home',
    })
    .when('/:section', {
        controller: function(r){
            return r.section+'Ctrl';
        },
        templateUrl: function(r){
            return 'app/views/pages/'+r.section+'.html';
        }
    });
}]);
```

Comment: What is `r` injected in your controller?

Comment: That was my attempt at trying to extract the "section" from the route provider, it was used as an example as to what i am trying to do as that works for the templateUrl but i know its not the right approach for controller

Comment: You can check this library https://github.com/GrumpyWizards/ngDynamicRouting or approach presented here http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/dynamically-loading-controllers-and-views-with-angularjs-and-requirejs